# If Magical Curses in Harry Potter only work on humans and other tangible objects, how did Voldemort curse the DADA position, if it was intangible?

Tags: harry-potter

As stated in the title above. How do you curse a non-intangible thing? I know you can curse people, and they experience pain or something unpleasant, or objects which destroy them, but how do you curse something intangible?

Comment: I've added a second dupe since it also refers to the (in-universe) inability to work out how the curse works or how to break it.

Comment: @Valorum _showoff :D_

Comment: @Gallifreyan - It's a moderately useful tool. It saves having to reopen stuff and wait for it to get closed again.